# Threaded, non-blocking websocket client

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket

I am wanting to run a program in Python that sends a message every second via web sockets to a Tornado server. I have been using the example on websocket-client;

This example does not work, because `ws.run_forever()` will stop the execution of the while loop.

Can somebody give me an example of how to correctly implement this as a threaded class which I can both call the send method of, but also receive messages?

```
import websocket
import thread
import time

def on_message(ws, message):
    print message

def on_error(ws, error):
    print error

def on_close(ws):
    print "### closed ###"

def on_open(ws):
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org/", on_message = on_message, on_error = on_error, on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()

    while True:
        #do other actions here... collect data etc.
        for i in range(100):
            time.sleep(1)
            ws.send("Hello %d" % i)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There's an example in their [github page](https://github.com/liris/websocket-client) that does exactly that. It seems like you started out of that example and took the code that sends messages every second out of the *on_open* and pasted it after the *run_forever* call, that BTW runs until the socket is disconnected.

Maybe you are having issues with the basic concepts here. There's always going to be a thread dedicated to listening to the socket (in this case the main thread that enters a loop inside the *run_forever* waiting for messages). If you want to have some other thing going on you'll need another thread.

Below is a different version of their example code, where instead of using the main thread as the "socket listener", another thread is created and the *run_forever* runs there. I see it as a bit more complicated since you have to write code to assure the socket has connected while you could use the *on_open* callback, but maybe it will help you understand.

```
import websocket
import threading
from time import sleep

def on_message(ws, message):
    print message

def on_close(ws):
    print "### closed ###"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://echo.websocket.org/", on_message = on_message, on_close = on_close)
    wst = threading.Thread(target=ws.run_forever)
    wst.daemon = True
    wst.start()

    conn_timeout = 5
    while not ws.sock.connected and conn_timeout:
        sleep(1)
        conn_timeout -= 1

    msg_counter = 0
    while ws.sock.connected:
        ws.send('Hello world %d'%msg_counter)
        sleep(1)
        msg_counter += 1
```

Comment: The whole server then runs in one thread? What if this thread becomes saturated?

Comment: @Paul: What do you mean by "saturated" here?

Comment: I meant that if it was using multiple threads, it could process much more data per second. With one thread, I feel you're not using your whole CPU and that thread can be overwhelmed with data relatively fast.

Comment: @Paul - threading wouldn't boost efficiency where no waiting is involved; at the end of the day, GIL ensures your still running one thread

Comment: python is decidedly not multithreaded.   if you want to handle lots of connections, you should use asyncio and multiprocessing to hand off the messages to other processes that do the work.

when you want to return a result to the client, you can then stuff it into a reply queue that gets picked up by the main asyncio process and returns

Comment: Is this possible but on the server side?

Comment: thanks for reminding me of specifying the thread as daemon

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, they have an updated example for [dispatching multiple WebSocketApps](https://websocket-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#dispatching-multiple-websocketapps)  using an asynchronous dispatcher like [rel](https://pypi.org/project/rel/).

```
import websocket, rel

addr = "wss://api.gemini.com/v1/marketdata/%s"
for symbol in ["BTCUSD", "ETHUSD", "ETHBTC"]:
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(addr % (symbol,), on_message=lambda w, m : print(m))
    ws.run_forever(dispatcher=rel, reconnect=3)  
rel.signal(2, rel.abort)  # Keyboard Interrupt  
rel.dispatch()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Not works, it still blocks!